# htaccess redirect trouble

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I use mod-rewrite and I do this:

```
RewriteRule ^brand/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\.\_]+)/?$ model.php?ref=$2&brand=$1 [NC]
```

and it works great! But I have a problem: when you go by url like

`brand/stuff/ffgfgfgfg.php` it will redirect to a page `brand/stuff/ffgfgfgfg?ref=ffgfgfgfg.php&brand=stuff`. I want to get rid of such a situation as it is not very good for the promotion on Google.

Maybe anyone can help me out and suggest a solution to redirect that awkward page?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. If you call brand/stuff/ffgfgfgfg.php, it will redirect to model.php?ref=ffgfgfgfg.php&brand=stuff, as it should. Let us know what you want to happen.

Comment: I want it to redirect it to brand/stuff/ffgfgfgfg

Answer (score 0):

Well here are your options. If, as you say in your comment (although I find it a bit strange) you want to redirect brand/stuff/ffgfgfgfg.php to brand/stuff/ffgfgfgfg, you can use

```
RewriteRule ^brand/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\.\_]+).php/?$ brand/$1/$2 [NC]
```

Apparently, if you want to redirect to brand/stuff/ffgfgfgfg?ref=ffgfgfgfg&brand=stuff, you could use

```
RewriteRule ^brand/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\.\_]+).php/?$ model.php?ref=$2&brand=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Does nothing... Just ignores it